# left and right barButtons font in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

What is the way to set custom font to left and right UIBarButtons of the UIImagePickerController?

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x212121)
imagePicker.navigationBar.translucent = false
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20.0)!]

// doesn't work
imagePicker.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 25.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
imagePicker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
imagePicker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need to subclass UIImagePickerController and set your own tool bar.

There is a great example from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

It's in objective-C but I'm sure it will give you an idea of what you need to do.